# Easy way of overwriting old rows in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've created a SSIS package with a script component that calls data from a JSON API and inserts it into a table in SQL Server. I've setup the logic to add new rows, however I want to find the most appropriate way to delete/overwrite old rows. The data is fetched every 4 hours, so there's an overlap of approximately 1000 rows each time the package is run.

My first thought was to simply add a SQL Task after the Data Flow Task that deletes the duplicate rows (with the smallest ID number). However, I was wondering how to do this inside the Data Flow Task? The API call fetches no more than 5000 rows each time, the destination table has around 1m rows, and the entire project runs in approx. 10 seconds.

My simple Data Flow Task looks like this:

[image]

Comment: "Is there a better way?" is a little off topic for Stack Overflow, as it can provide opinionated answers, like I'm about to do. One method would be to load all your data to a different table, and then rename your old and new tables. Then truncate the old one, and repeat the cycle for each load (so they swap names, effectively). Depends what your table is being used for though; which we have little to nothing to go on.

Comment: I edited the question to be less influenced by opinions. So you mean that I could create a setup that repeatedly swaps tables and names?

Comment: Effectively what it says on  the tin. Load into a table, swap the names, truncate old table. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: If you copy all the data each time you can use partition switching to turn the `rename/truncate` process into a single metadata operation that takes milliseconds. Otherwise, you can copy the new data into a staging table and use LEFT JOIN to find which rows already exist in the target table and whiche ones are new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main approaches you can try:

- Run Lookup on Row ID. If matched run OLEDB Command Transformation for each line with an UPDATE statement. If not matched - direct rows to OLE DB destination.
  Easy to implement, straightforward logic, but multitude of UPDATE statements will create performance problems.
- Create an intermediate table in DB, clean it before running Data Flow Task, and store all rows in your Data Flow into this intermediate table. Then on the next task - do either of following:

  - `MERGE` intermediate table with the main table. More info on [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
  - In transaction - drop rows from the main table which exists on the intermediate, then do `INSERT INTO <main table> SELECT ... FROM <intermediate table>`

I usually prefer the intermediate table approach with MERGE - performant, simple and flexible. MERGE statement can have downside effects when run in concurrent sessions or on clustered columnstore tables, then I use the intermediate table with `DELETE...INSERT` command

Comment: So I actually ended up doing the first one. In my case (solution I posted below), I don't have too many rows to scan and update. So performance isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 3):

So I figured out that the easiest solution in my case (the case where there's only relatively few rows to update) was to use the OLE DB Component as can be seen below.

[image]

In the component I added an Update SQL statement with logic such as the following

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[table]
SET    [value1]=?,
       [value2]=?,
       [value2]=?,
WHERE  [value1]=?
```

Then I mapped the parameters to their corresponding columns, and made sure that my where clause used the lookup match output to update the correct rows. The component makes sure that the "Lookup Match Output" is updated using the columns I use in the Lookup component.

[image]